# webpack - TypeError: this.lib.createConnection is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack, sequelize.js

I was having an error called `Error: Please install mysql2 package manually`.

To solve this issue, I added `dialectModule: "mysql2"` into sequelize config file and it worked.

But another error occurred which is called `TypeError: this.lib.createConnection is not a function`

I only face with this issue after running webpack bundled file.

I also checked online to fix this and I found the solution is that removing `"dialectModule": "mysql2"` line from the config file but this was the solution of my previous issue.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "sonar": "node sonar-project.js",
    "test": "nyc mocha --timeout 10000",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development&& node -r dotenv/config ./src/server",
    "start-test": "set NODE_ENV=test&& node -r dotenv/config ./src/server",
    "build": "webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='production' --progress --colors",
    "recreate": "cd .. && sh recreate.sh",
    "dev": "node ./src/server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.2.10",
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
    "cryptr": "^6.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "license-key-gen": "^0.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.14",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "rand-token": "^1.0.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "sinon": "^9.2.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "uniqid": "^5.2.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.0.9",
    "websocket": "^1.0.33",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "ws": "^7.4.1",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.8.0",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "null-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name : "server",
    entry: './src/app.js',
    mode : process.env.NODE_ENV,
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new Dotenv({
            path: `./.env.${env == "production" ? "production" : (env == "development" ? "dev" : "test")}`
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "src/grpc/proto", to: "src/grpc/proto" }
            ]
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"]
    },
    externals: ['pg', 'sqlite3', 'tedious', 'pg-hstore'],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
        __dirname: true
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port : 400
    }
};
```